# Deploying additional files with Visual Studio to target VM

Tags: visual-studio, inf

I asked chatGPT about it, and it said I can just add additional files, and it will work. Now I can get it to work for the exact directory that contains my .SYS files, but any other directory does not work.

Project output is then: "out/Open/Open.sys" so INF file contains:

```
[Open.DriverFiles]
Open.sys

[SourceDisksFiles]
Open.sys = 1,,
Open.man = 1,, ; MY NEW ENTRY

[SourceDisksNames.amd64]
1 = %DiskId1%,,

[Strings]
DiskId1                 = "Open Device Installation Disk"
```

So when `Open.man` is right next to `Open.sys` the file does appear in `C:/DriverTest/Drivers/` on the target VM.

But if I try to use a subdirectory:

`Open.man = 1,\lower,`

So that it is:

```
out/Open/Open.sys
out/Open/lower/Open.man
```

it does not work. What is the magic needed here to be able to specify where the file lives?

Ultimately, it will be something like
`../x64-Debug/modules/os/windows/Open.man`